# WPF, estilo para botones en XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf

Soy programador C# y estoy recién utilizando WPF y quisiera replicar estos botones en xaml, empezando por su forma!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Básicamente estos controles se crean con estilos (Styles) y propiedades adjuntas (Attached Properties), en ocasiones también puedes utilizar Desencadenadores (Triggers) con el lenguaje XAML.

Por ejemplo, puedes crear un botón de la siguiente manera, mediante un archivo de recursos o en el mismo XAML de tu página:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:botoncito="clr-namespace:MiProyecto.PropiedadesBoton">
    ...
    <Style x:Key="Imagen1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=(botoncito:ButtonProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></Image>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></ContentPresenter>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Definimos las propiedades adjuntas (Attached Properties) mediante código C#:

```
public class PropiedadesBoton
{
    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(PropiedadesBoton), new UIPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));
}
```

Por último, en tu archivo XAML, donde utilizarás el botón en sí, puedes colocar el siguiente código:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Imagen1}" botoncito:ButtonProperties.Image="{StaticResource MyImage}" Content="Test">
</Button>
```

El [tutorial proveído por MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb613545(v=vs.100).aspx) es bastante interesante y completo para aprender a realizar esta tarea. Casi todos los controles WPF pueden personalizarse.

Comment: Un millón de gracias, pude entender parte de tu código pero me esta dando problemas esta linea botoncito:ButtonProperties.Image="{StaticResource MyImage}" sera por el namespace de mi proyecto o algo parecido?

Comment: botoncito:ButtonProperties.Image="{StaticResource MyImage}" Es por el recurso, debe ser el que hayas creado como recurso en tu XAML.